# Cron job appears to work, but no changes seen in file

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I have a simple cronjob that uses curl to download a file and save the contents to a file.  The crontab file reads:

```
45 17 * * * /home/my_username/public_html/./update_md.sh
```

where `update_sh.md` =

```
#!/bin/bash

curl https://docs.google.com/document/d/FILE_ID/export?format=txt > page.md
```

where `FILE_ID` is the unique file ID for my google document.

The email output I get shows a successful curl report, but the file `page.md` does not get updated.  I can verify that when I run the `curl` command manually, it shows the same success report *and* updates `page.md`.

Email report:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed  Time    Time    Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload  Total  Spent    Left  Speed
101  2229    0  2229    0    0  9814      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 12247
```

Bash output when running manually:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
101  2229    0  2229    0     0  11957      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 15697
```

Any idea why `page.md` is not updating through the cronjob but will update just fine my running the command manually?

Comment: You're not specifying the directory where the file should be saved. Check in your home directory.

Comment: Absolutely right! Thank you, that solved my problem.  I'm sorry I'm so green I can't even upvote your comment, but if you want to post as an answer I will gladly accept.